# SQL nested SELECT with JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wasted all the day on one query without success , **SOS** I need a help :) with a given **@CustomerId** , I need to query all the Products that linked to customer seller can sell but **not** sold to him before  , the Commissions table is indication of what products seller can sell

[image]

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: How do you know which products a seller can sell? By the commissions table perhaps?

Comment: I can query it from Commissions table with SellerId

Comment: @DimaRudaev: You are connecting `customer` and `product` through `sales` table? how you determine whether product been sold or not?

Comment: a "Products" table name is bad choice , you can consider it like "Categories"

Comment: each record in Sales table indicates a sale , customer can purchase only 1 of each products

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT sellableProduct
FROM (SELECT Comissions.ProductId AS sellableProduct, Sellers.SellerId AS sellableSeller FROM Comissions INNER JOIN Sellers ON Comissions.SellerId=Sellers.SellerId INNER JOIN Customers ON Sellers.SellerId=Customers.SellerId WHERE Customers.CustomerId = @customerid) AS tblSellable
LEFT JOIN (SELECT Sales.ProductId AS soldProduct, Customers.SellerId as soldSeller FROM Customers INNER JOIN Sales ON Customers.CustomerId=Sales.CustomerId WHERE Customers.CustomerId = @customerid) AS tblSold
ON tblSellable.sellableProduct=tblSold.soldProduct AND tblSellable.sellableSeller=tblSold.soldSeller
WHERE tblSold.soldProduct IS NULL
```

this way you avoid time-consuming IN statements

If a Customer can only have one Seller, then you can omit the seller link:

```
SELECT sellableProduct
FROM (SELECT Comissions.ProductId AS sellableProduct FROM Comissions INNER JOIN Sellers ON Comissions.SellerId=Sellers.SellerId INNER JOIN Customers ON Sellers.SellerId=Customers.SellerId WHERE Customers.CustomerId = @customerid) AS tblSellable
LEFT JOIN (SELECT Sales.ProductId AS soldProduct FROM Sales WHERE Sales.CustomerId = @customerid) AS tblSold
ON tblSellable.sellableProduct=tblSold.soldProduct
WHERE tblSold.soldProduct IS NULL
```

Comment: I edited the solution, nevertheless you're welcome to find the word "customers" yourself...

Comment: It works , thank you very much i really appreciated it , it is very complicated query !!! You are a SQL-NINJA - RESPECT

Comment: i need to enhance it a little bit , your query return ProductId's i want to JOIN them with Products.Name and Products.Description , does it possible somehow to add a "JOIN Products ON ProductId" to this query ?

Comment: yes that's possible. In `FROM (SELECT` add the additional columns and the inner join. Also add the columns in the `SELECT` at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you're looking for products that have a record in `commissions`, but not in `sales`. Using `:id` to denote the specific ID:

```
SELECT *
FROM   products
WHERE  productid IN (SELECT productid
                     FROM   commissions
                     WHERE  sellerid = :id) AND
       productid NOT IN (SELECT productid
                         FROM   sales
                         JOIN   customers ON sales.customerid = cusomers.customerid
                         WHERE  sellerid = :id)
```

Comment: you mean that i need to query associated SellerId to given customer and then run your query with :id = SellerId  ?

Comment: "sales.sellerid" there is no sellerid field in sales Table

Comment: arg, wasn't paying attention. Fixed.

Comment: let me understand , you tell me to query it by SellerId that i can query it from Customer table with @CustomerId ??

Comment: your query answers to question "which products a seller can sell that he didn't sold before" and i need an answer to question "which products a seller can sell that he didn't sold before to specific customer @CustomerId" , thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
SELECT sell.*, prod.* FROM 
Sellers sell
INNER JOIN Customers cust ON cust.SellerId = sell.SellerId
LEFT JOIN Commissions comm ON sell.SellerId = comm.SellerId
LEFT JOIN Products prod ON prod.ProductId = comm.ProductId
WHERE prod.ProductId NOT IN (
SELECT ProductId
FROM Products p INNER JOIN 
Sales s ON s.ProductId = p.ProductId
WHERE s.CustomerId = @CustomerId
```

It get all the sellers and the respective product from commission, where the product Id is NOT associated with any sale of the client

Comment: syntax error - Line 7 Ambiguous column name 'ProductId', also only 1 seller associated with each customer